# Como calcular a porcentagem de likes?

Tags: php, javascript, matemática

Como posso encontrar um jeito de calcular dois valores para chegar em uma porcentagem, por exemplo: Tenho `100` likes em uma variável e `10` dislikes em outra. Neste exemplo,(100 - 10 = 90) `90%` das pessoas que o leram gostaram... Este é um exemplo muito simples, mas e se por exemplo eu tivesse `921320201` likes e `201312` dislikes, como eu efetuaria essa equação?

Comment: Devo discordar de 100 likes e 10 dislikes resultarem em 90% de aceitação. Eu diria que tem `100/(100+10) = 90.909...%` de aceitação. Isso afeta bastantes quando os números são mais próximos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apliquei a fórmula (likesPositivos/totalLikes) * 100 = porcentagem

```
<?php 
$likesPositivos = 5000;
$dislikes = 2500; 
$totalLikes = $likesPositivos + $dislikes;

$porcentagem = ($likesPositivos/$totalLikes) * 100;

echo $porcentagem;
```

Comment: Está com erro esse exemplo. Notice: Undefined variable: likes in C:\wamp64\www\teste.php on line 6

Comment: Editei a resposta. Agora não vai disparar o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer saber qual a ocorrência de determinada característica em um conjunto. Se todo elemento tem peso igual, a fórmula é:

```
Contagem de indivíduos com a característica / total de indivíduos
```

No caso, você tem dois tipos disjuntos de indivíduos:

- like
- dislike

Então, podemos transformar a fórmula em:

```
likes / (likes + dislikes)
```

No caso, obteremos um número entre `[0,1]`. Essa é a proporção em termos absolutos. Para pegar em termos percentuais, basta multiplicar o resultado por 100.

Não se esqueça de fazer a operação com números reais no lugar da divisão inteira.

Segundo [esse post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12832557/4438007), PHP já trabalha com divisão real por padrão. Segundo [esse post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228376/4438007), o JavaScript também trabalha assim.