# Média no banco de dados em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Pessoal tenho o seguinte cenário no banco de dados:

Tabelas:

```
mdl_question_attempts (slot, questionid, rightanswer, responsesummary)

mdl_quiz_slots (slot, quizid, questionid)
```

Na tabela `mdl_question_attempts` são registradas as tentativas de respostas a um determinado quiz. `questionid` é o `id` da questão, `rightanswer` é a resposta correta, `responsesummary` é a resposta dada pelo aluno.

Na tabela `mdl_quiz_slots` são registradas as questões que foram aplicadas aos alunos, onde `questionid` é o `id` da questão, `quizid` é o `id` do questionário (conjunto das questões aplicadas).

Gostaria de ter a média de acerto por questão de um determinado quiz.

Comment: Qual o formato de cada campo? `rightanswer` seria um `boolean`?

Comment: Calcular média com o comando avg() do mysql

Comment: @RORSCHACH não está claro se ele quer calcular média de alguma nota. Me parece que ele quer saber quantas vezes a questão foi respondida corretamente sobre o total de vezes respondida.

Comment: @LeonardoPessoa para cada resposta correta pode se considerar como valor positivo 1, os formatos rightanswer e responsesummary  é texto, para saber se está correta deve ser considerado apenas as linha onde rightanswer = responsesummary, e responsesumarry é diferente de NULL

Comment: @LeonardoPessoa é isso mesmo, quantas vezes a questão foi respondida corretamente sobre o total de vezes que a questão foi respondida. acho que assim eu teria a media de cada questão, isso?

Comment: A fórmula está nessa questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236471/64969 ; não está em SQL, mas dá a ideia geral de como prosseguir. Basta calcular o total de indivíduos / indivíduos de dado grupo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho que o problema é um pouco mais complexo, não sou programador profissional por isso minha dificuldade.
Eu consigo fazer a media geral do quiz (todas as questões) minha dificuldade é como fazer a média por questão, levando em cosnideração que um quiz pode ter quantidades diferentes de questões.
esta quantidade é obtida na tabela mdl_quiz_slots onde são cadastradas as perguntas do quiz

Comment: A modelagem é a mesma: contar indivíduos da população total, contar indivíduos que satisfazem determinada condição, dividir o segundo pelo primeiro.

Comment: minha dificuldade está em obter o resultado por questão

Comment: Vdd dvd, tens razão,  vou ter que ver como posso diferenciar os questionários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em consideração que você só quer fazer o cálculo descrito na pergunta (*a média de acertos por questão*), logo acredito que a tabela `mdl_quiz_slots` não seja necessária entrar na query. A query abaixo retorna:

- **id_questão:** `id` da questão
- **total_respostas:** quantidade de respostas para cada questão
- **acertos:** número de acertos
- **media_acertos:** porcentagem de acertos em relação ao total de respostas de cada questão

**Query:**

```
select distinct(questionid) as id_questao,
count(questionid) as total_respostas,
sum(
   case when responsesummary = rightanswer
   then 1 else 0
   end
) as acertos,
concat(
   round(
      sum(
         case when responsesummary = rightanswer
         then 1 else 0
         end
      )
      / count(responsesummary) * 100
   ),'%'
) as media_acertos
from mdl_question_attempts
group by questionid
```

Comment: DVD, quase matou o problema! rsrs

Comment: DVD, quase matou o problema! rsrs
é quase isso que quero, a tabela mdl_quiz_slots é quem vai classificar as questões por questionários, por exemplo, um questionário pode ter 20 questões, outro 30 e por aí vai, então acredito que seria necessário  fazer um INNER JOIN entre `mdl_quiz_slots` e `mdl_question_attempts`, onde posso colocar este INNER JOIN em seu código?
assim poderei fazer um where para mostrar apenas a media de determinado questionário (Quiz)

Comment: @MiguelSilva Como poderia dar um `inner join` se a primeira tabela não possui uma coluna relacionada à segunda tabela?

Comment: a coluna slot na tabela mdl_questions_attempts recebe valor da coluna slot da tabela mdl_quiz_slots.

Comment: @MiguelSilva É porque pegunta não dizia. Se quiser alguma ajuda.

Comment: desculpe, realmente não dizia, estou enfrentando problema quando faço o inner join, das duas tabelas referenciando questionid das duas tabelas, recebo erro dizendo que a expressão questionid é ambíguo,  estou implementando em seu código,  sabe dizer o que pode ser?